# How to set and read an NTAG213 with a password?

Tags: android, nfc

I was considering ordering NTAG213 and replacing my current implementation of NTAG203 chips as the new line of chips have password protection as given [here](http://www.smartrac-group.com/de/pm/2014/453/smartrac-introduces-new-ntag213-nfc-tags-offering-features-like--nfc-forum-n-mark-compatibility-and-uid-mirror-functionality)

Is there a way in android we can write a password and read back the data when supplied with a password?

Comment: No this tag supports password protection, but not sure if android supports reading and writing passwords in it.

Comment: I dont know much about NTAG213.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The complete feature set of the NTAG213 is accessible, configureable and useable in Android. The tags are recognized as compatible with MIFARE Ultralight by Android, so you can either use the `MifareUltralight` or `NfcA` technology to communicate with them.
N.B.: Please, be aware that submitting the wrong password to a tag may lock it permanently if it has been configured with a maximum retry count.

Comment: I was reading this, http://developer.android.com/reference/android/nfc/tech/MifareUltralight.html Could not find anything related to password, do i need to use sector level commands?

Comment: You would use the `transceive()` method and pass any password-related command as `byte` array. The `MifareUltralight` class only contains helper methods for commands that are common to all MIFARE Ultralight tags.

Comment: Oh have not used commands, always used direct API calls. Any reference would be helpful? I looked up http://members.nfc-forum.org/specs/spec_license/document_form/custom_layout?1394204523283 , could not understand much.

Comment: I suggest you have a look at the NTAG213 datasheet at http://www.nxp.com/documents/data_sheet/NTAG213_215_216.pdf. You will find that chapter 10 contains all the details, e.g. from section 10.7 you can derive that you send `new byte[] {0x1B, p[0], p[1] ,p[2], p[3]}` (without any CRC as that will be supplied by Android) to do password authentication (`p[i]` are the 4 password bytes).

Comment: Thanks, i managed to use transreceive to increase the counter value in ntag203, i am sure ntag213/216 password should be similar.

Comment: I finally managed to lay my hands on a ntag216[not ntag213], so should i use MiFareUltralight class or some other?

Comment: I figured out MiFareUltralight does not work for ntag216, so i used NfcA class. Thanks for all the details.

Answer (score 1):

Usually, Android supports the [NFCA](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/nfc/tech/NfcA.html) standard. However, at some point, if you want to access protected data, it depends on the encryption standard if it is supported by default (e.g., several [mifare](/questions/tagged/mifare) [standards](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/nfc/tech/TagTechnology.html)), or if you have to implement it on your own, using the raw [transceive](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/nfc/tech/NfcA.html#transceive%28byte%5b%5d%29) command:

```
//Send raw NFC-A commands to the tag and receive the response.
byte[]   transceive(byte[] data)
```